# SQL Server - Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, where-clause

I keep getting an: "Incorrect Syntax Error near the keyword 'WHERE'.

And I am having the 'most' difficult time finding out why.  I've eliminated all syntax errors except this and I am at a loss.  Any help would be appreciated.
The WHERE clause --- I put surrounded in ** where ** for you.   Extra set of EYES needed!

```
DECLARE @vEndTime DateTime
Declare @vStartTime DateTime
DECLARE @sql4 nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @parameters nvarchar(4000)
SET @parameters = '@vStartTime boards.DateEnd, @vEndTime boards.DateEnd'
set @vEndTime = '09/24/2011 12:00:00:00'
set @vStartTime = (SELECT MAX(DateEnd) FROM [UICTransfer_Archive].[dbo].[StageLotLineage])

WHILE @vStartTime < '09/24/2011 12:00:00:00'

BEGIN 

SET @vEndTime = DATEADD (minute , 60 , @vStartTime )

select @sql4 = N'

INSERT INTO [UICTransfer_Archive].[dbo].[StageLotLineage](LineName, BoardBarcode, MachineProductName, DateStart,
DateEnd, MachineName, PlacementTime, RefID, CircuitNumber, FeederSlot, FeederTrack, Component,
LotNumber, ReelID)

SELECT 
       boards.LineName
      ,SUBSTRING(boards.BoardBarcode, 1, 5) AS BoardBarcode
     -- ,board.BoardBarcode
      ,boards.MachineProductName
      ,convert(varchar,boards.DateStart,120)
      ,convert(varchar,boards.DateEnd,120)
      ,placements.MachineName
      ,convert(varchar,placements.PlacementTime,120)
      ,placements.RefID
      ,placements.CircuitNumber
      ,placements.FeederSlot
      ,placements.FeederTrack
      ,locations.Component
      ,locations.LotNumber
      ,locations.ReelID
  FROM [UICTransfer_Archive].[dbo].[TrnsBoardComplete] as boards
   LEFT JOIN [UICTransfer_Archive].[dbo].[TrnsPlacements] as placements
      ON placements.BoardCompleteID = boards.BoardCompleteID
   LEFT JOIN [UICTransfer_Archive].[dbo].[TrnsLocations] as locations
    ON (locations.FeederSlot=placements.FeederSlot and
locations.FeederTrack = placements.FeederTrack and
locations.FeederStack = placements.FeederStack and
locations.FeederPallet = placements.FeederPallet and
locations.MachineName = placements.MachineName and
placements.PlacementTime >= locations.DateValidated and 
(placements.PlacementTime <= locations.DateInvalidated 
or locations.DateInvalidated IS NULL) 
**where boards.DateEnd >= @vStartTime 
 and boards.DateEnd <= @vEndTime 
 and placements.CircuitNumber IS NOT NULL '**

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql4,@parameters,@vStartTime, @vEndTime
--select @@rowcount

SET @vStartTime = DATEADD (minute , 60 , @vEndTime )

END
```

Comment: you open a bracket `ON (locations` but never close it.

Comment: From what you posted there is no need for dynamic sql or any looping here at all. This could be done as a single insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a closing bracket to the end of your join.

> or locations.DateInvalidated IS NULL) **)**

```
(locations.FeederSlot=placements.FeederSlot and
locations.FeederTrack = placements.FeederTrack and
locations.FeederStack = placements.FeederStack and
locations.FeederPallet = placements.FeederPallet and
locations.MachineName = placements.MachineName and
placements.PlacementTime >= locations.DateValidated and 
(placements.PlacementTime <= locations.DateInvalidated 
or locations.DateInvalidated IS NULL))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your comment to me helped out.  Up and running now.  This is a great forum.